# How to detect whether apple device has a physical home button in Flutter?

Tags: ios, flutter

How would I detect in Flutter if the current device (iPhone) has a physical home button or hasn't, like: iPhone X, iPhone Xs, iPhone Xs Max, iPhone Xr ?

I know you can get the model from `device_info_plus` but is there a more efficient way?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would you even want to know? I can't imagine an app needing to behave different based on that fact.

Comment: I am scaling some widgets based on screen size, but the modern Apple phones seem to look different than everything else when I use this approach

Comment: So it sounds like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Having the home button seems irrelevant. It just seems to be the case that you have a problem with devices that happen to have a home button. Maybe try to write up a question specifying the exact problem. Show us what result you get from devices that work correct and the ones that don't, preferably with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so people can help you better.